# imagettftext do not work

Tags: php, gd, freetype, imagettftext

I try this code with `imagettftext()`:

```
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

But it does not work as it should, I have GD and FreeType installed, as you can see:
[image]

Anyone can point me in right direction?

Comment: Hello, what is the error displayed? (to see it, access your image directly after removing the content-type header).

Answer (score 1):

Assign variable $font to the absolute path of the font file.

Comment: Changed to absolute path, still the same problem :(

Comment: Nop, the code i pasted in main post is the only code I try to run.

Comment: What kind of error message you are getting? ex: a blank page or invalid image symbol

Comment: I get an invalid image symbol

Comment: try by cleaning the output buffer. ob_clean(); place it before imagepng function

Comment: Actually I just solved the problem by using `putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));` as they mention in the docs

Answer (score 1):

```
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';
```

Your code is looking for "arial.ttf" that does not exist. Please copy the font file (arial.ttf) into the same directory of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your path to font

```
$font = 'arial.ttf';
```

on

```
$font = __DIR__ .'\Arial.ttf';
```

or use absolute path (it's not correct but working), if you using windows system

```
$font = 'c:\WINDOWS\Fonts\Arial.ttf';
```